# Have a communicating variable between two files in React

Tags: reactjs

So I have a value that changes in two different functions in two different react files.

I want this value to be a var that communicates between the two files in a way that both can edit it and see the edits.

I tried doing something like this in file1:

```
export default {
    value: false,
};
```

And this in file2:

```
import myVar from '../file1';
```

And it seems to work well, besides the fact that I wasn't able to edit the "value" also from file1.

I tried doing all of these:

```
this.value = false;
value: false;
value = false;
```

But of course, I get an error in all of them.

So, is there a way to edit the value also from file1? Or is there another better method two have this common variable that can be read and edited between file1 and file2?

Thanks

Comment: `import var from '../file1';` sounds like a typo

Comment: It works well. I was able to import the var and even edit it in my second file2. The problem is I don't know how to edit it back in fil1, I don't even know if it's possible at all.

Comment: `var` is a reserved word in javascript

Comment: Yeah, I actually used a different specific word. I wrote var here to make it more general. But thank you for pointing out I will edit it.

Comment: `myVar.value = 3`

Comment: Yes, this is what I did on file2 to edit it. (file2 is the file I imported the var to). But for file1 how do I edit the value in there inside a fucntion?

Comment: What do you mean by that? You're exporting an object, when you import it you import that object.

Comment: I need to find a way of having one value communicating between file1 and file2. Meaning, a variable that can be read and edited between the two files. And that the two files are aware of the edits of the other file and so on. I tried doing it this way, and it worked well beside not being able to edit the variable inside the file I imported it from in a function. Any idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: Define "aware". Again--you export an object; if you change object properties in a different module it's still the same object.

Comment: "Aware" meaning that if I change the variable on file2, and I edit it, I will see that change also when I access the variable on file1. I need this type of connection. This is one way I tried, works well besides not being able to edit again in file1. Any other idea on how to achieve this goal?

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're saying. You're exporting an (essentially) anonymous object--you should export an actual object with a reference in the defining file (see Leonardo's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that object doesn't exist in file1 until it reaches the export statement;
if you need to modify the object in `file1` you need to have reference to it somehow;
you can try this way;

file1:

```
const myObject = {
    value: false,
};

// modify the value by this reference
myObject.value = "changed";

export default myObject;
```

in file2:

```
import myVar from '../file1';


// you can also modify it here
myVar.value = 3;
```